# Should a question be closed AND downvoted? Or just closed?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, closed-questions

I've seen a few questions in the past few days where the poster included a minimal example, wrote an okay description of their problem, and asked a question that turned out to be unrelated to the solution to their problem. For example, it turns out that they had a typo in the code.

My understanding is that these questions should be closed as

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced
>   or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be
>   on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help
>   future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely
>   inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem
>   before posting.

The question is whether these questions should also be downvoted. It seems to me that the author of the question made an honest mistake, but included all the necessary parts for a good question.

Here's the two sides to the argument that I could see:

1. Pro-downvoting: The question won't be useful by anyone else. Downvoting is a signal that you shouldn't pay it any attention in search results etc.
2. Anti-downvoting: Downvoting a question has a negative effect on the author's reputation. The elements of the question reflect the author's ability to phrase a good question. In this case, they simply made a mistake interpreting their issue.

Comment: It should be closed, downvoted, the asker should be mocked in comments, then they should be bulled on twitter and other social media.

Comment: That is entirely up to you. I wouldn't downvote if the question was well-researched, well-written, and included all necessary parts. But, again, that's your call when you're behind the wheel. Also, not all (but most) typos should be closed.

Comment: I'll vote to close when the close reasons apply. I'll downvote when I think the question is crap. Sometimes the two overlap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It seems to me that the author of the question made an honest mistake, but included all the necessary parts for a good question.

You're focusing on the wrong thing. Even though votes have for side-effect to encourage good contents and discourage bad contents because they affect the reputation of the people who posted, **the primary use of votes is to judge not the person who posted but the post itself.** If a question "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful", then downvote it. Whether the question comes from an honest mistake is irrelevant. If one of the close reasons fit, also vote to close it.

Answer (score 17):

You should be evaluating whether to close and whether to downvote separately.

Vote to close the question if it meets any of the criteria for closure.  Don't vote to close if it doesn't meet any criteria for closure.

Downvote the post if:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

They will frequently happen to overlap, but they won't always overlap.